# Office 365 - Yammer REST API - Rate limited due to excessive requests

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, yammer

In our project we are using Yammer REST API for getting yammer search results. We are using JMeter tool for load testing in our application when the tool tries to send more than 30 API calls per 10 seconds it is throwing the following error:

> Error : {"response":{"stat":"fail","code":33,"message":"Rate limited
>   due to excessive requests."}}

Request url:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json?search='OurSearchKeyword'&page=1&num_per_page=10
```

Is this due to the Rate limits for the Yammer REST API that is discussed in this link: [REST API rate limits](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits)

Can you please explain on what is the reason for getting this error? Is there any threshold in yammer settings for the number of requests on the Yammer APIs? If so whether it can be modified or not?

Answer (score 0):

That link you provided has the answer to your question.  You are exceeding the maximum number of requests within a certain amount of time.  As the link states, you can make 10 requests per 10 seconds (or 30 seconds, depending on the resource).

Comment: If so is there a way to increase the number of requests for Yammer.

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to increase these limits.